# How to make Cartesian Product of CSV files in Java?

Tags: java, csv, set, guava, cartesian-product

I want to do **Cartesian Product** of multiple CSV files in Java.
I will be getting **n** number of CSV files in a request, I have to generate one single file containing Cartesian Product of these CSV.

CSV Files will look like -

[image: Cartesian Product]

**Cartesian.csv** is expected csv.

For this I have parsed the CSV file and generated Sets and passed to [Google Guava library's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct%28java.util.List%29), **Sets.cartesianProduct()** method

For this method we have to pass sets like `Sets.cartesianProduct(productSet, pricingSet, addressSet)`

But in my request I will get **n** number of CSV files, so how can pass dynamic number of Sets or Array of Sets to **Sets.cartesianProduct()**?

Is there any library available to make **Cartesian Product** of CSV files in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the [varargs version](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct(java.util.Set...)) of `Sets.cartesianProduct`, use the one which takes a list: [`Sets.cartesianProduct(List<? extends Set<? extends B>>)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct(java.util.List)).

Comment: How to call Sets.cartesianProduct(List<? extends Set<? extends B>>), I mean what to pass it?